# Changing Restlet logging level to other than FINEST causes service to be unresponsive (jar conflict?)

Tags: jar, https, restlet, java.util.logging

When starting a Restlet service I wrote, I use the call:

```
Engine.setRestletLogLevel(Level.WARNING);
```

to limit the logging messages, and the service does not respond to client requests.  If the level is changed to FINEST, then it works.  Even when it is set to FINEST, the service sometimes becomes unresponsive, which I suspect is related.

I have used this call in other of my Restlet implementations and it works fine.

Notes: Using HTTPS protocol, Restlet jar version is 2.1.4 . My code is written in Scala jar version 2.9.2, jvm is 64 bit version 7, commons-logging-1.1.1.jar

**Update:** Modified the service so that it uses http instead of https, and everything works fine, but that's not how it needs to work.  This leads me to believe that the jars I am pulling in have a conflict, but I do not know how to diagnose or resolve it.